# Set-AzAppServicePlan - Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I keep getting an error of :

- Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'

I am not sure how to solve this case ? Could you please advise ? I am very bad this :(

from

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName 'backend-lowmode-atnight' -Name 'backend-lowmode-atnight' -Tier "Shared" -Debug
```

This is my full code

```
try
{
    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
catch {
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
    throw $_.Exception
}
Set-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName 'backend-lowmode-atnight' -Name 'backend-lowmode-atnight' -Tier "Shared" -Debug
```

Comment: can you tell where you are trying this code

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I am using this in the Azure automation account - Runbook PowerShell script.

Comment: Using azure automation runbook, I am able to run the above code without any conflicts as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/ksXwD57.png). @JaruwittA.

Comment: Hi, I will try this over the weekend and report back right away!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in your case, *"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'"* error might come if you are trying to change the tier to *"shared"* but it is already in a *"shared"* tier. So verify the current tier once and modify it accurately to avoid conflicts.

Your code for modifying an app service plan setup looks correct. However, in order to run through the automation account runbook, you must first provide **Web plan contributor** role by going to this
*Path*: `Automation account -> Account settings -> Identity`(Make sure that the system identity is enabled) as shown below.  Only then can you make modifications for an app service plan using `set-AzAppservicePlan`.

[image]

*After given the above permissions, I tried the same script as yours and was able to reflect those changes successfully in an app service plan.*

```
try
{
   "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
catch {
   Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
   throw  $_.Exception
}
Set-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName 'Jahnavi' -Name 'newplan' -Tier "Shared" -Debug
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Plan modified accordingly:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! However I am still getting the same error : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'

I have created a System assigned Identity already - azure role assignment Web Plan Contributor however still getting the same error.

Is it because I have many apps in the resource group ? 

This is my identity

https://ibb.co/stMpZYK

This is my resource group : 

https://ibb.co/Y7q0jZM

This is my code powershell - 

https://ibb.co/T13dmSQ


Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Are you giving all the resource group names and web app names correctly. Can you verify again? @JaruwittA.